# Three.js Importing Blender model: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm trying to import a Blender model into three.js with the [Three.js Blender Export](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender) tool. However, I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

I've tried browsing other Stack Overflow threads, and I've tried to use `THREE.ObjectLoader()` instead. However, I get this error instead `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`.

I'm currently using version R83 of three.js.

Here's my code: (I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html).)

```
var scene, camera, renderer;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var speed = 0.01;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    initMesh();
    initCamera();
    initLights();
    initRenderer();

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function initCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
    camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function initRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha: true} );
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function initLights() {
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
    scene.add(light);
}

var mesh = null;
function initMesh() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('js/cube.json', function(geometry, materials) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 0.75;
        mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
        scene.add(mesh);
    });
}

function rotateMesh() {
    if (!mesh) {
        return;
    }

    mesh.rotation.x -= SPEED * 2;
    mesh.rotation.y -= SPEED
    mesh.rotation.z -= SPEED * 3;
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    rotateMesh();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();
```

This is how my cube.json looks like:

```
{
    "metadata":{
        "generator":"io_three",
        "type":"BufferGeometry",
        "position":23382,
        "version":3,
        "normal":23382
    },
    "data":{
        "attributes":{
            "position":{
                "type":"Float32Array",
                "itemSize":3,
                "array":[...]
            },
            "normal":{
                "type":"Float32Array",
                "itemSize":3,
                "array":[...]
            }
        },
        "index":{
            "type":"Uint16Array",
            "itemSize":1,
            "array":[...]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the exporter settings from `Type: BufferGeometry` to `Type: Geometry`. Hopefully this will help if anyone is stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Including "Scene" in exporter settings fixed that problem for me, and allowed exporting as Buffergeometry and reading in Three.js with an ObjectLoader without issues.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how you load the model in?